# remove repeated string character from every line in a file in Unix

Tags: string, file, unix, lines

I have a file in Unix that has a '\' character at the end of every line. I would like to remove it from every line. There are over 1000 lines.

I have seen some examples, but didn't quite work. I am new to Unix and hoping I would get my answer here.

Thanks,

Ab

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
sed -i.~ 's@\\$@@g' file.txt
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- `-i` do the substitution for real in the file
- `.~` makes backup files with this suffix
- `s@@@` is the skeleton syntax for substitutions (I have arbitrary chosen `@` as delimiter)
- `$` mean end of line

Comment: I am sorry, but what at the other characters in quotes?

Comment: It's not `--i` but `-i`. If really you don't have the later switch, try this : `sed 's@@@g' origin > file && mv file origin`

Answer (score 0):

This eliminates the last character of e
sed 's/.$//' original_file > new_file

Answer (score 0):

A `Perl` one-liner.

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/\\$//' file
```

This will create a backup of the original with a `~` extension and replace every `\` at the end of each line.